Apache Seatunnel, how to make http post call
I want to knwo the http post example
I see the reference but not found syntax for http post
https://seatunnel.apache.org/docs/2.3.5/connector-v2/source/Http
https://seatunnel.apache.org/docs/connector-v2/source/Http/

{
"result_table_name": "all_users_api_result",
"plugin_name": "Http",
"url": "http://example.com/api/users/graphql",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
"body": "{\"query\":\"query GetAllUsers($filter: UserFilter) { getAllUsers(filter: $filter) { userId userName email role status createdDate lastLoginDate } }\",\"variables\":{\"filter\":{\"status\":\"ACTIVE\"}}}",
"format": "json",
"poll_interval": 3600,
"json_field": {
    "userId": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].userId",
    "userName": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].userName",
    "email": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].email",
    "role": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].role",
    "status": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].status",
    "createdDate": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].createdDate",
    "lastLoginDate": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].lastLoginDate"
},
"schema": {
    "fields": {
        "userId": "string",
        "userName": "string",
        "email": "string",
        "role": "string",
        "status": "string",
        "createdDate": "string",
        "lastLoginDate": "string"
    }
}

}

example：
https://github.com/apache/seatunnel/blob/ec1c3198bcffb8ff6b41014c36d4ddacedb03868/seatunnel-e2e/seatunnel-connector-v2-e2e/connector-http-e2e/src/test/resources/http_formrequestbody_to_assert.conf#L27
https://github.com/apache/seatunnel/blob/ec1c3198bcffb8ff6b41014c36d4ddacedb03868/seatunnel-e2e/seatunnel-connector-v2-e2e/connector-http-e2e/src/test/resources/http_jsonrequestbody_to_assert.conf#L28
You only need to configure method and body
source {
  Http {
    url = "http://example.com/example/jsonBody"
    method = "POST"
    body = "......"
    
    ......
  }
}


thanks, It helps me to acheive the task. I have updated the final response as below
